# создать стол в sqlite3_db с помощью класса в Pycharm(Django)

Tags: python, django, sqlite3, pycharm

В общем прописал в Apps своё
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в models описал, что я хочу создать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с помощью `python manage.py migrate`

Создал бд, но внутри моего стола нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Comment: А не нужно ли было какой-нибудь скрипт (миграции, например) из джанго прогонять?

Comment: В том то и дело, что я не знаю), возможно и нужно, пытаюсь повторить отсюда, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5g3-qJZbhy8&index=2&list=PLpTASIMYgCp8supkEmnnrYa5xi9g91ZPI, но человек работает не в Pycharm, может есть какие то особенности, не знаю

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/intro/tutorial02.html . Еще на хабре было полно статей про то как начать с джанго работать

Comment: Сапсибо. разобрался, нужно было  в Installed Apps дописать к "article" - 'article.apps.ArticleConfig',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно было в Installed Apps дописать к "article" - 'article.apps.ArticleConfig',

детальнее тут : https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/intro/tutorial02.html, спасибо gil9red